# Why does Webpack pass functions imported as ES modules into an Object call in Webpack 4?

Tags: webpack

Here's some contrived code:

```
// index.js
import { log } from './log';

log('hello world');

// log.js
export const log = string => console.log(string);
```

Building this without a config yields the following stringified source:

```
"__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony import */ var _log__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./log */ \"./src/log.js\");\n\n\nObject(_log__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"log\"])('hello world');\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/index.js?")
```

The bit I'm interested in is this:

```
"Object(_log__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"log\"])('hello world');"
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why the log function has been passed into an `Object` call.  I've taken a look at the [commit where this was introduced](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/1ebca7e55df2a9caa4cf78d9c0bcfeb260bb3cdd), but trying to pass functions with context into that call don't seem to unbind them–it'll just return the reference as is.

Any help figuring out why this exists is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for wrapping the export in a call to the Object constructor is to call the export as a plain function instead of a method on a Webpack exports object.

Webpack does not strictly implement the spec when it comes to ES6 modules and simplifies things by turning exports into properties on a Webpack exports object, as opposed to static bindings. When a function gets added to an object in JavaScript, it becomes a "method" and `this` references the object it's defined on *when that function is invoked as a method*.

In your example, Webpack is avoiding invoking your module export as a method on the export object.

```
_log__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"log\"]('hello world')  // WRONG invoking `log` as a method
```

vs

```
Object(_log__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"log\"])('hello world')  // RIGHT invoking `log` as a function
```

They are using the Object constructor in a clever way since it will just [return any function passed to it unmodified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object). They could accomplish the same thing by using an extra variable assignment.

```
const temp = _log__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"log\"]
temp('hello world')
```

See the Webpack tests for handling `this` binding for ES6 modules [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/test/configCases/parsing/harmony-this/index.js) and an issue filed for [breaking ES6 module spec](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7213) with regard to exporting arrow functions.

See also [documentation on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) which should be `undefined` in ES6 module scope since [modules are always in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) where `this` in a function body is `undefined` instead of `window` or a reference to an exports object.